# Mapping FSX to windows instance; getting error

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, amazon-fsx

```
{
  "schemaVersion": "2.2",
  "description": "Map SMB Share using SMBGlobalMappings for Windows Containers",
  "mainSteps": [
    {
      "action": "aws:runPowerShellScript",
      "name": "runPowerShellWithSecureString",
      "precondition": {
        "StringEquals": [
          "platformType",
          "Windows"
        ]
      },
      "inputs": {
        "runCommand": [
          "$username = (Get-SSMParameterValue -Name plasmausername).Parameters[0].Value",
          "$password = (Get-SSMParameterValue -Name plasmapassword -WithDecryption $True).Parameters[0].Value | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force",
          "$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)",
          "New-SmbGlobalMapping -RemotePath '\\\\amznfsxzijoxmju.plasma.com\\share\\' -Credential $credential -LocalPath D: -RequirePrivacy $true -ErrorAction Stop"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to map FSX share to windows instance, I have joined domain still getting this error:

```
New-SmbGlobalMapping : The parameter is incorrect.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SmbGlobalMapping -RemotePath "\\\\amznfsx5galhhax.file.onetechnow ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_SmbGlobalMapping:ROOT/Microsoft/...mbGlobalMapping) [New-SmbGlobalMapping], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 87,New-SmbGlobalMapping
```

username is in the format: file.onetechnow.com/Admin

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue while following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/using-amazon-fsx-for-windows-file-server-on-eks-windows-containers/) blog:

Remove the single quotes from the following line:

```
New-SmbGlobalMapping -RemotePath '\\\\FSxDNSNAME\\share\\Directory'
```